# For what chemical purpose did soldiers in WW2 carry small ion exchange resin columns in their survival kits?

Tags: water, water-treatment

My textbook [Chemistry Live, Declan Kennedy] states that ''During WW2 small ion exchange resin columns were part of a soldier's survival kit.''. I can't find any further info about this online or elsewhere. The chapter is on water purification and hard/soft water.

My thoughts are to either 1) to aid purification of urine for consumption 2) to remove ions from water that has been poisoned 3) to purify water that may be polluted due to all the metal waste (bullets, shrapnel, etc.)

Can anyone confirm the actual reason that soldiers carried these kits ?

Comment: Sites such as https://www.wearethemighty.com/mighty-history/this-is-the-average-gear-a-soldier-in-ww2-carried/ do not support this. Or, if they were handed out they may not have gotten carried for very long.

Comment: I believe all your guesses are way off. Ion exchangers are used to make _sea water_ potable. Not sure they were around as early as WWII, though.

Comment: Why a down vote for this perfectly valid question with a reference? Ion exchangers played a big role in WWII and a subject of intense study in the 1940s-70s.

Comment: Still, the unwanted foreseen use what to make water pounds or whatever more drinkable. It was a survival kit, at the end.